# Testack white unable to find window's children

Tags: automation, white-framework, teststack

I have a WPF app that I try to automate using testack white and I'm pretty much stuck at the point where I cannot get any children for a Window (which is embedded in a Panel which is the main Window)

The problem I believe is not necessarily with white but how this app is built because (I'm using VisualUIAVerifyNative as inspector. I tried others as well but haven't seen any children in ControlView, ContentView or RawView):
- opening the inspector and expand the tree till that window it shows that this doesn't have any children
[window_element_no_children](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mg54q.png)
- however, if I use Focus Tracking/Hover on mouse feature (e.g. while pressing CTRL the inspector then gives you whatever element the mouse is hovering) then the whole subtree for this window then shows up. Unfortunately, even though I try to find the children at this point through my automation test it still returns me none.
[window_element_with_children](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym8Xx.png)

Does anyone have any idea how exactly I can "force" a check on this window so that the children will then be displayed? Same as how FocusTracking in inspector works like.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using AutomationElementFinder?

```
var children = new AutomationElementFinder(window.AutomationElement).Children(
                AutomationSearchCondition.All);
```

You can try other SearchCondition too.

Comment: That was indeed good but unfortunately didn't work for me. What I've done in the end was navigate that tree using the arrows (yak ... luckily the tree is not that big to spend years to traverse it) as once a node was selected I was able to retrieve its name ... definitely not ideal but, as I said, couldn't get a dev to look into how the app was built and nail down the problem